# Как игнорировать подпапку с названием совпадающим с названием репозитория?

Tags: git

Я пользуюсь `Gulp`, который собирает все в подпапку, название которой совпадает с корневой папкой проекта. Как добавить такую папку в .`gitignore`? Структура репозитория:

```
Project/
   .git/...
   node_modules/...
   src/...
   Project/... // вот эту папку надо добавить в .gitignore
   package-lock.json
   packege.json
   gulpfile.js
   .gitignore
```

Сложность в том, что вместо Project там может быть любое название.

Comment: если путь после Project более-менее уникальный, то можно написать `*/path/to/your/*`

Comment: Если в корневую папку больше ничего не добавляется, то можно просто заигнорить всё

Comment: Может научиться пользоваться инструментом... не очень понятно, зачем это?